# mssql search a varchar field for invalid typo

Tags: sql-server, validation, wildcard

I have a field with names in it.  They can be last name, first name middle name/initial

Basically I want to find all names that aren't normal spellings so I can tell someone to fix their names in the system.

I don't want to select and find this guy
O'Leary-Smith, Timothy L.

But I would want to find this guy
<>[]}{@#$%^&*()/?=+_!|";:~`1234567890

I can just keep coming up with special characters to search for but then I'm just making this huge query and having to bracket wildcards... it's like 50+ lines long just to say one thing.

Is there something (not some custom function)
that lets me say

```
where name not like 
A-Z
a-z
,
.
'
-
```

possibly something that is

```
where name contains anything but these ascii characters
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this is a one of fix-up; a negated character class:

```
where patindex('%[^ A-Za-z,.''-]%', name) > 0
```

Although more letters than A-Z can appear in names ...

Comment: Thanks for this.  That makes so much sense.
true about the other character thing.  This is to hand off to someone else to scrutinize.  We had a lot of test people entered into a system and I'm just trying to find any odd ones

Answer (score 1):

If it's just odd characters you're looking for:

```
WHERE name like '%[^A-Za-z]%'
```

The `^` acts as a `NOT` operator.